# Unable to render the data from API on first mount

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios for data fetching in my react app. I need to render the list of data as soon as the component mounts. The data fetching from the API runs well in my localhost. But as soon as my app goes into production, the data fetching on first time mounting is not called i.e. the data is not fetched from the API at first. It shows blank. I have to refresh the page to load the data.

I have tried following many approaches to call API using axios like returning promise and using try-catch blocks and even conditional data calling on the basis of response status, but every time the problem remains same.

This is how my component goes:

```
class Users extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        usersData: [],
        dataFetched: false,
        renderData: false,
        current_page: 1,
        total_data: '',
        per_page: 5,
        currentUsers: [],
        searchUser: ''
    };
  }


  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  fetchUsers = async () => {

    await axios.get(GlobalData.BASE_URL+'api/user/list', {headers:GlobalData.headers})
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({ 
            usersData: res.data.data, 
            total_data: res.data.data.length,
            dataFetched: res.data.status,
            renderData: true 
        }, () => this.formatData());

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }


  formatData() {
    const indexOfLastPost = this.state.current_page * this.state.per_page;
    const indexOfFirstPage = indexOfLastPost - this.state.per_page;

    const currentUsers = this.state.usersData.slice(
      indexOfFirstPage,
      indexOfLastPost
    );
    this.setState({ currentUsers });
  }


  handleClick = number => {
    this.setState({
      current_page: number
    }, () => {
      this.formatData();
    });
  };


  setID = (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target.id)
    var fetched_id = e.target.id;
    this.setState({fetched_id}, () => this.getMsgList(fetched_id));

    //console.log(e.target.id)
}

  getMsgList = (fetched_id) => {
    if(fetched_id){
      this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/users/userdetail',
      search: '?user='+fetched_id
      });
  }
}


  handleInput = (e) => {
    let input_status = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      searchUser: input_status
    });
  }


  render() {
    let filteredUserStatus = this.state.currentUsers.filter( e => {
      return e.status.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchUser.toLowerCase());
    });

    console.log(filteredUserStatus)

    const { per_page, total_data, current_page, currentUsers }  = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <Row>
          <Col xl={12}>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                  <Row>
                    <Col lg="8">
                      <h4>Users List</h4>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg="4" md="12">
                        <Input type="text" placeholder="Search user status..." className="search_box" onChange={this.handleInput} />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>

                  <Row style={{marginTop: 15}}>
                    <Col lg="12">
                      <Button className="float-right" onClick={()=>this.props.history.push('/users/createuser')}>Create User</Button>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <Table responsive hover>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">S.No</th>
                      <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  { total_data ?
                        currentUsers.map( (datum, i) => (

                        <tr className="data-slice" key={i}>
                            <td>{datum.id}</td>
                            <td>{datum.user_name}</td>
                            <td>{datum.first_name}</td>
                            <td>{datum.last_name}</td>
                            <td>
                              <Button id={datum.id} color="primary" onClick={this.setID}><i className="icon-pencil"></i></Button>
                              <Button id={datum.id} color="danger" onClick={()=>alert('Item to be deleted!')}><i className="fa fa-times"></i></Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        ))
                        : <tr><td>No Data!</td></tr>
                    }
                  </tbody>

                </Table>
                {
                  this.state.renderData === true ? 
                    <CustomPagination
                      per_page={per_page}
                      current_page={current_page}
                      total_data={total_data}
                      handleClick={this.handleClick}
                    />
                :
                null
                }

              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Users;
```

Also, my web page is hosted over unsecured server, if that is the cause to improper data fetching?
Please help to identify the issue.

Comment: How you are saying the first time it's not working? Did u face any error from API? @bubble-cord

Comment: No problem from API. First time I am saying because it works on local but not on production.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/Rotarepmi/exjson/db")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({ json });
      });
  }
```

Comment: What difference will it make in using this approach? If you explain ? The data returned form API is already converted to JSON format in axios